# Does it make any sense to graph 1/T versus ln(Kc)?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, free-energy

I calculated $K_c$ experimentally for the reaction $$\ce{CO2 + H2O -> H2CO3}$$ at different temperatures. Because $\Delta G =-RT\ln(K)$, I thought that graphing 1/T against $\ln(K_c)$ would give me a gradient $\Delta G/-R$, that I could calculate googling the Gibbs free energy of formation of the compounds of my reaction to compare to the gradient I get to check accuracy. Does this make any sense? (because the values I calculated were wrong)

Comment: Note this equation Delta G =-RTln(K) is wrong. It should be $\Delta G^\circ =-RT\ln(K)$. The circle (plimsoll) symbol is important, it means "in the standard state".

Comment: How do you measure the concentration of $\ce{H2CO3}$ ?

Comment: @Maurice by titrating with NaOH

Answer (score 5):

As

\begin{align}
Δ_\text{r}G°&=-RT\ln{(K)}\\
Δ_\text{r}G°&= Δ_\text{r}H° - TΔ_\text{r}S°
\end{align}

then

\begin{align}
\ln{(K)} = -\frac{Δ_\text{r}G°}{R}\cdot \frac{1}{T}  &= - \frac{Δ_\text{r}H°}{R} \cdot \frac{1}{T} + \frac{Δ_\text{r}S°}{R}\\
\ln {\frac{K_2}{K_1}}&=   \frac{Δ_\text{r}H°}{R}\left(\frac{1}{T1}-\frac{1}{T2} \right)
\end{align}

with the $Δ_\text{r}H°$ and $Δ_\text{r}S°$ are assumed approximately constant in the range $T_1–T_2$ and $K_i$ is the equilibrium constant for the respective temperature $T_i$.

The slope value $\dfrac{\text{d}\ln{K}}{\text{d}\left(\frac{1}{T}\right)}$  could be used directly to determine  $Δ_\text{r}G°$ only if $|Δ_\mathrm{r}S°| \approx 0$ and therefore the regression line passes the origin, what is generally not the case. But it can still be determined from the values of both the slope and the intercept, as below:

Therefore:
\begin{align}
Δ_\text{r}H° &= −R \cdot   \text{slope}\\
Δ_\text{r}S° &= R \cdot   \text{intercept}\\
Δ_\text{r}G° &= −R \cdot   \left(\text{slope} + T \cdot \text{intercept} \right)
\end{align}

For more, see the Wikipedia page about [the van 't Hoff equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_equation).

Comment: Thank you for the information! Just a small correction to the last equation: it should be slope + T*intercept. I think.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Fixed